# Is there any difference between CMD ["./start.sh"] and CMD ./start.sh in docker file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to create a docker file in which my API file which is named as start.sh should be running in the background when I run it in the container.Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd), there is 2 ways to use `CMD`: as a *shell* form, or an *exec* form.

> Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell.